# Windows Phone 8 Style

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application using xaml. I have almost finished my project. On testing I notice that the application theme color is changing when I change the phone's theme color via settings. I need red color theme for my application (button selection, textbox border,progressbar color etc). What should I do to maintain constant style irrespective of phone's theme? Should I add style for each and every component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create new resource dictionary and include it in App.xaml (merge dictionaries). Override all default styles for all controls you'll be using. Now, use those styles for all your controls and you will be fine. Since your controls will pull styles from App.xaml, your application will be styled according to your desires.

You can find styles in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Design, this will give you an idea what to change. Or get some of styles with Expression Blend (edit template).